# subscribe is not a function while testing the service

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am writing a jasmine test to test service call in angular. I have used jasmine.createSpyObj to spy on service.  I am currently getting error

```
this.agreementsService.getOutstandingAgreements(...).subscribe is not a function
```

My spy contains a return observable not sure what the problem is ?

Component

```
public getOutstandingAgreements(Id: number) {
    this.agreementsService.getOutstandingAgreements(Id).subscribe((data: AgreementsModel[]) => {
         this.myData = data;
         if (this.myData) {
         this.agreementData = this.myData[0].data;
         this.agreementLength = this.myData.length;

         this.calculateRemainingDaysLeft(0);
        }
        });
    }
```

Test file

```
describe('AgreementComponent', () => {
      let component: AgreementComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<AgreementComponent>;
      let  mockAgreementsService: AgreementsService;



        const mockAgreementsService = jasmine.createSpyObj('AgreementsService', {
        getOutstandingAgreements: () => of(['Adam West']) ,
        updateAgreement: () => Promise.resolve([])
      });


      configureTestSuite(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [SharedModule, FontAwesomeModule],
          declarations: [AgreementComponent, CustomScrollDirective],
          providers: [{ provide: UserService, useValue: mockUserService },
          { provide: AgreementsService, useValue: mockAgreementsService }]
        });
      });  


      fit('should  call getOutstandingAgreements', () => {
        const response: AgreementsModel[] = [];
        let outStandingAgreementSpy: jasmine.Spy;
        let outStandingAgreementServiceSpy: jasmine.Spy;
        setupComponent();
        outStandingAgreementSpy = spyOn(component, 'getOutstandingAgreements').and.callThrough();
        //outStandingAgreementServiceSpy = spyOn(mockAgreementsService, 'getOutstandingAgreements').and.returnValue({ subscribe: () => {} });

        component.ngOnInit();
        expect(outStandingAgreementSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(mockAgreementsService.getOutstandingAgreements).toHaveBeenCalled();
        //expect(outStandingAgreementServiceSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return something with a `subscribe` method, as the component calls subscribe directly from `getOutstandingAgreements`. Just return what you need with a `subscribe` function, e.g:

`and.returnValue({ subscribe: () => {} });`

Or a real observable:

`and.returnValue(Observable.of('some value'));`

---

In other words, mock the getOutstandingAgreements as follow:

```
let agreementsService: any = {
    getOutstandingAgreements(): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.of('you object');
    }
};
```

Comment: If you see in my test method i have commented the line outStandingAgreementServiceSpy  which does what you are saying . The reason why i have commented is because it says you cannot spy again as it is already spied in the code earlier